# Probabilistic Taylor theorem for concave functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, convex-analysis, taylor-expansion

This [paper](https://sci-hub.se/10.1016/0167-7152(93)90122-y) proves a probabilistic version of Taylor's theorem

\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}g(X) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{g^{(k)}(0)}{k!} \mathbb{E}X^k + \frac{\mathbb{E}X^n}{n!} \mathbb{E} g^{(n)}(X_{(n)}),
\end{equation*}
where $X_{(n)}$ is another random variable derived from $X$ and $g^{(n)}$ is the $n$-th derivative of $g$. Suppose we  take $n=4$ and we know that $g^{(4)} < 0$ (e.g. due to concavity), then it seems to follow that
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}g(X) =  \sum_{k=0}^{3} \frac{g^{(k)}(0)}{k!} \mathbb{E}X^k  +  \frac{\mathbb{E}X^4}{4!} \mathbb{E} g^{(4)}(X_{(4)}) > \sum_{k=0}^{3} \frac{g^{(k)}(0)}{k!} \mathbb{E}X^k.
\end{equation*}
Hence we can get explicit upper bound on $\mathbb{E}g(X)$. However, a *crucial assumption* in the probabilistic Taylor theorem is that $X$ is non-negative. This means we cannot apply the result to a centered random variable like $X-\mu$, where $\mu = \mathbb{E}X$. Suppose again that $g^{(4)} < 0$. Are there any results that would allow me to conclude something like the following?
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}g(X-\mu) = \sum_{k=0}^{3} \frac{g^{(k)}(0)}{k!} \mathbb{E}(X-\mu)^k  +  \frac{\mathbb{E}(X-\mu)^4}{4!} \mathbb{E} g^{(4)}(Y) > \sum_{k=0}^{3} \frac{g^{(k)}(0)}{k!} \mathbb{E}(X-\mu)^k,
\end{equation*}
where $Y$ would be another random variable linked to $X-\mu$.

**Edit** : Positivity of $X$ is needed in the proof, since the Fubini theorem is used. Many theorems of this sort seem to require positivity, see also "A probabilistic analogue of the mean value theorem" on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem).

**Edit**: For example, $X_{(1)}$ in the Theorem has density
\begin{equation*}
P(X_{(1)} < x) = \frac{\int_0^x P(X>t) dt}{\mathbb{E}(X)}.
\end{equation*}
Similar densities can be derived for $X_{(n)}, n \ge 2$. Hence it is clear that some type of positivity is needed in the statement, otherwise $\mathbb{E}(X)$ can be zero and $X_{(n)}$ is no longer well defined.

**Edit**: This question is now answered on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430450/probabilistic-taylor-theorem-for-concave-functions).

Comment: Intuitively the condition that $X$ is non-negative does not look that crucial. Expand $g(x)$ by Taylor, plug in $X$ and take expectation. Unforuntately the paper you linked is not publicly accessible. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: @KurtG. I've uploaded a new link to the paper and a reference to Wikipedia. It seems positivity is needed due to the use of Fubini's theorem. One can directly see that $\mathbb{E} X $ cannot be equal to zero in the theorem, since $X_{(4)}$ is no longer well defined.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is answered on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430450/probabilistic-taylor-theorem-for-concave-functions).